# html page width is different when rendered from server

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

For an html page, `$(window).width()` is giving different values when its hosted on server.
My laptop's resolution is 1920 X 1080.
When I open the page locally on Firefox and Chrome, the width is shown as 1920. The same page when I hosted on a server and when its opened, the width is shown as 1097. Why is this difference? Due to this difference the whole layout of the page is different. How I can solve this?

P.S When the page is opened in IE, the width is same on local and server. 
I'm using Zurb's foundation framework (3.2).

Comment: What do you mean by "opened on the server"?

Comment: I've uploaded to a remote server and using the http URL, I've opened the page.  By 'Local', I meant the html preview using the preview option in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Don't trust Dreamweaver's preview - it is, after all, merely a preview. Test in your web browser on your local machine instead.

Comment: Surely the window's width depends on the resolution of the screen you are using to view the page no matter where the site is sitting

Comment: I tested the page on web browser on locahost (wamp on my machine) and its giving the  actual width i.e 1920 when the resolution is 1920.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jS not run into  the server **window** has some property for Width like this

```
window.outerWidth
window.innerWidth
```

that change on re size browser screen with get log from window you can see all property in developer tools

```
console.log(window);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Google Chrome. Apparently media queries get messed up if the page is zoomed in or out. Make sure your zoom level is 100% for both sites.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the issue and believe actually nothing (Ubuntu 12.04, Mozilla Firefox 26.0)
http://www.potomek.eu/blog/media/differentscreenwidthissue.jpg